# Want to use LINQ instead of foreach but it doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, linq, loops

In the following code `foreach` loop works fine, but when I try to use `LINQ` instead of using `foreach` it doesn't work no exception no error.

This code is working :

```
    public static IEnumerable<PatternInfo> LoadPatterns() {
        var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(PatternFullPath);
        var dirs = directoryInfo.EnumerateDirectories();
        var result = new List<PatternInfo>();
        foreach (var info in dirs)
        {
            result.Add(new PatternInfo
                           {
                               PatternName = info.Name,
                               TemplateFileNames = GetTemplateFiles(info.FullName)
                           });
        }
        return result;
    }
```

But this one not :

```
    public static IEnumerable<PatternInfo> LoadPatterns() {
        var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(PatternFullPath);
        var dirs = directoryInfo.EnumerateDirectories();
        var patterns = dirs.Select(info => new PatternInfo {
            PatternName = info.Name,
            TemplateFileNames = GetTemplateFiles(info.FullName)
        });
        return patterns;
    }
```

Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: When you say no exception, no error, what is actually happening? You have an enumerable with 0 items when you collapse it?

Comment: The linq query will not execute until you need it,  PatternFullpath may have changed by the time you use the IEnumerable.  do a patterns.ToList() and see if that fixes your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference between the two is that in the first code sample you have a `List<PatternInfo>`, all items in the list are populated already - then you return this list as `IEnumerable<PatternInfo>`.

In the second example you have a `IEnumerable<PatternInfo>` - this will only load the patterns when you iterate over the enumeration for the first time.

If you want the second version to be equivalent (eager loading of the patterns) then add a `ToList()`:

```
return patterns.ToList();
```

Comment: What a mistake :P ,I forgot that LINQ is lazy, thank you all so much. :D

Answer (score 2):

Well, enumerables are lazy until someone starts enumerating over them, so:

```
foreach (var item in LoadPatterns())
{
    ...
}
```

The `.Select` statement in your second example simply returns a new `IEnumerable<T>` but until there is some code that consumes/loops over this enumerable nothing will actually execute.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ is deferred execution. You're returning the statement, but it doesn't get evaluated until you do something to iterate over the `IEnumerable` you're returning. What is the code that calls `LoadPatterns()`?